# Sum multiple values in the same column, if the respective cell below (in the same column) is not empty

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I hope someone can help me.
I have a table in excel which looks something like this:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | January |  |
| 2 | Sales | 4324 |
| 3 | Expec. Sales | 3324 |
| 4 |  |  |
| 5 | February |  |
| 6 | Sales | 3423 |
| 7 | Expec. Sales | 2543 |
| 8 |  |  |
| 9 | March |  |
| 10 | Sales | 5234 |
| 11 | Expec. Sales | 2653 |
| 12 |  |  |
| 13 | April |  |
| 14 | Sales | 6534 |
| 15 | Expec. Sales | 4453 |
| 16 |  |  |
| 17 | May |  |
| 18 | Sales | 4356 |
| 19 | Expec. Sales | 4392 |
| 20 |  |  |
| 21 | June |  |
| 22 | Sales |  |
| 23 | Expec. Sales | 3942 |
| 24 |  |  |
| 25 | July |  |
| 26 | Sales |  |
| 27 | Expec. Sales | 2942 |
| 28 |  |  |
| 29 | August |  |
| 30 | Sales |  |
| 31 | Expec. Sales | 4023 |
| 32 |  |  |
| 33 | Sum of Sales | Sum of sales of months with data |
| 34 | Sum Expec. Sales | sum of Expec. Sales where Sales in that month has data |

The problem is that:

- the sum sales is only supposed to include the cells, when there is a value in the cells
- the sum of expected sales should only include months that have already passed

The order of the cells cant change, so the visual style of the table has to be kept the same.

Comment: *the sum of expected sales should only include months that have already passed* would they show in the data if not passed yet?

Comment: As you can see in the image, all month until august are included, but the data for sales only yet goes until may, while the data for the expected sales is already visible for all months

Comment: Please post sample data as markdown sample data. Include your own attempt at solving your issue for debugging purposes.

Comment: Then you could use this for the expected sales in addition to Harun's answer: `=SUMIFS(B2:B31,A2:A31,"expec. sales",B1:B30,"<>")`

Comment: Note the shift of range for the second condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sum of `sales`-

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B31,A2:A31,"Sales")
```

For sum of `Expec. Sales`-

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B31,A2:A31,"Expec. Sales")
```

> ***Edit:*** Use below formula to sum `Expec. Sales` where there are values on sales.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX(FILTER(A2:B15,A2:A15="Sales"),,2)>0)*(INDEX(FILTER(A2:B15,A2:A15="Expec. Sales"),,2)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The problem is, that I only want the sum for the expected sales, when there is also a value in the "Sales" for the same month.

Comment: @XY Try edited formula. `=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX(FILTER(A2:B15,A2:A15="Sales"),,2)>0)*(INDEX(FILTER(A2:B15,A2:A15="Expec. Sales"),,2)))`

Comment: Ty so much for the solution. It works. Can you tell how I can edit it, when the "Sales" and "Expec Sales" in the opposite order? What I mean is that it always first shows "Expec Sales" then "Sales".

Comment: @XY Same formula should work. Try it first. Also if it works then accept the answer (tick mark).